# Is there a way to use Play routing in scala js files?

Tags: scala, playframework, scala.js

I use Play! Scala 2.4 with scala js, and I would like to know if there is a way to get the routing config file from the scala js files.

It would be very convenient since it would allow me to replace urls as string by something like `application.routes.Application.admin()`.

Do you know any workaround to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [javascript reverse routing](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaJavascriptRouting).
It will help you to define routes from your js code.
It will look like this:

```
@helper.javascriptRouter("jsRoutes")(
  routes.javascript.Application.admin
)
...
<script>
   console.log(jsRoutes.routes.Application.admin())
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

Supporting the previous answer, you can take a look at my code for a rather complex real-world example.

[The JavaScript side](https://github.com/jducoeur/Querki/blob/master/querki/scalajvm/app/views/client.scala.html#L45-L77)

[The Scala.js facade around that](https://github.com/jducoeur/Querki/blob/master/querki/scalajs/src/main/scala/querki/comm/ClientRoutes.scala)