# How to use reverse routing in Akka Scala.js app?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http, scala.js

I have used the [Akka HTTP with Scala.js example](https://github.com/vmunier/akka-http-with-scalajs-example) as a starting point for my application (without Twirl support).

For example, one of my route looks like this:

```
 path("mycode.js") {
        encodeResponse {
          getFromResource("public/client-fastopt.js")
        }
      }
```

This works perfectly but the static route `public/client-fastopt.js` really bad to maintain, because when I switch to full optimization, the file name changes. Is there a way to achieve reverse routing, e.g. calling something like this `getFromResource(MyScalaClass.getPath())`?

Furthermore, I noticed that I get a 404 because `/client-fastopt.js.map` cannot be found. Do I have to create an additional, separate route for this file or is there a more convenient way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Akka HTTP doesn't provide reverse routing like the Play framework does, and integration of Akka HTTP with Play is still [experimental](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/AkkaHttpServer).  Nevertheless, Play's [Javascript Router](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaJavascriptRouting) and other Scala.js specific suggestions as described in this StackOverflow [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36135204/is-there-a-way-to-use-play-routing-in-scala-js-files) might be of interest to you.